# jquery resize() to center multiple dynamic width divs

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Here's the situation:

I have 3 full width sections that have vertically centered titles and left aligned button divs.
When we resize, I want to center the button, which is currently position:absolute.

*Here was my idea :*
Upon Resizing Window

1. Capture Width of Outer Div
2. Capture Width of Inner Div
3. Subtract Inner from Outer to determine leftover space
4. Divide Leftovers into 2 equal Margins
5. Apply using .css() to tack the Margins on either side of the Inner Div.

And here's what I've scripted based on that idea.

```
jQuery( window ).resize(function() {

    var parentWidth = 
    $( ".search__btn--wrapper" ).parent().width();

    var childWidth = 
    $( ".search__btn--wrapper" ).width();

    var marginWidth =
        parentWidth - childWidth;

    var halfWidth = 
        marginWidth/2;

    $( ".search__btn--wrapper" ).css("left" , halfWidth);
    $( ".search__btn--wrapper" ).css("right" , halfWidth);

    console.log('width is now' + $( window ).width() );
    console.log('parent of button element width:' + parentWidth );
    console.log('button element width:' + childWidth );
    console.log('leftover margins' + marginWidth );
    console.log('needed margins' + halfWidth );

});
```

**The Problem(s) so Far**
Even though I'm able to get the widths of both the outer and the inner on *every* resize, For some reason the **marginWidth** variable does not update.
Same for the **halfWidth**

I'm also trying to have this work dynamically for each instead of just the first, but that's secondary and I feel like would just require some sort of `.each()` loop.

What am I missing for the first part though?
I feel like it's something easy that I'm just overlooking :<

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't understand what you need to write your code in jQuery and not in CSS. You can center an absolute div in a div relative with:

```
position:absolute;
left:0;
right:0;
margin:0 auto;
```

Comment: This is pretty much what I did in a previous portion of the site. It wasn't until I looked further into it that I saw what I was missing in order to get the Text middle aligned.

I needed to add a line-height to cheat the system since it wouldn't middle out for me otherwise. Thanks for the reminder!